# Webcam - brightness adjustment does not work on windows camera or MS teams but works with webex, zoom

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, webcam

I have got a webcam (Tukzer TZ-C01-WHT), but my video was very dark (Windows 10). So, I emailed the Tukzer support and they told me how to user brightness on windows camera app/zoom. They told that by default the webcam brightness is kept at minimum for privacy. So I tried that, and the brightness controls are working fine in zoom/webex, I am able to increase brightness so that my video is no more dark. However, the brightness controls don't change anything in MS teams or Windows Camera App.
Here are some screenshots:

[image: zoom]
[image: windows camera app]

I found some information on ffmpeg [here](https://superuser.com/a/1569345/456878), but the control box seemed to be of no use. It does not change anything at all.

Please help. Is it a webcam issue or windows issue.

Comment: A third-party tool, such as the portable Webcam Settings Tool, from https://ekiwi-blog.de/download/webcam/WebcamSettings_portable.zip , gives access to many camera features which Windows has hidden. If this works for you, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Hey, I tried this, but it just gives a new interface for settings given by ffmpeg. It does not change anything for me.

Comment: voted up as this tool is much easier to use than manually finding ffmpeg settings. But this does not help my case.